# Passing hibernate.connection.datasource from Spring's applicationContext xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

Earlier I had datasource configured in the application server itself and I am passing it to application level hbr.xml file as

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource</property>
```

Now I have configured datasource in applicationContext.xml as

```
<bean id="mydatasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydatasource;maxPoolSize=100" />
            <property name="username" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>

    </bean>
```

How to pass this to hbr.xml file?
Based on the given below my another question is that what should be the class for my session factory? Should it be `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`
OR

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the datasource along with the hibernate mappings into your DAOs:

```
<bean id="mydatasource" ...>
  ...
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="mydatasource" />
  <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
      <value>path/to/your/mappings.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props><!-- see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html -->
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
      ....
    </props>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

Using annotations you could access your datasource through the injected bean

```
@Resource
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
...
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Comment: I have 100+ DAOs. Do I have to change all of them?

Comment: Not knowing your DAO implementations I can only guess. But perhaps usings a generic DAO could decrease that amount significantly. You can find one such implementation (though many other postings about this topic exist) under this entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721383/hibernate-crud-generic-dao