# When should I close HIbernate Session Factory in JSF web application?

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory

I am developing a JSF Web Application which is using Hibernate. I have created a singleton class for Session Factory, but when do i need to close the session factory object? I am currently closing each Session object at end of DAO method. What about session factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionFactory -> Open it once during the web application start up and close it on webapp stop. ServletContextListener could be one place. That should be good enough.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775599/how-would-i-obtain-sessionfactory-from-the-servletcontext-in-the-dao/49270145#49270145 the following thread using Servlet Context is not a good approach. Can you please let me know if there is any other way?

Comment: Will session factory get closed automatically if server is shut down?

Comment: If server is shutdown, it won't call close method automatically and entire JVM process is killed and so no objects exist. Going thru link https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#close() will help why we should close sessionfactory.